# The Literature on the impact of outliers on ordinary least square (OLS) regression

Tags: least-squares, references, outliers

I remembered I have encountered a paper in 1960s or 1970s that explore the impact of outliers on ordinary least square (OLS) regression. In the paper, it is shown that just adding one outlier will significantly reduce the adjust R2.

Does anyone still remember that paper?

Comment: Was Google Scholar of any help?

Comment: thank you very much.  I googled but failed.

Comment: Any reason you want to dig up a paper from the 1960s when there are probably plenty of other modern  papers that say the same thing?

Comment: There's a specific issue whether one means "outlier in y but not in x-space", vs "outlier in x-space but not in y" vs "outlier in both" (as well as with how you define outlier). The last of the three options is a very serious problem in regression, since if an outlier is far enough away from the rest of the data it can pull the line right to it, essentially ignoring everything but the mean of the remaining data. Depending on which you mean, the $R^2$ doesn't necessarily decrease.

Comment: Can you provide some frequently cited modern papers on the subject, @ShawnHemelstrand ?

Comment: thank you very much @Glen_b  I am referring to "outlier in y but not in x-space"

Comment: This book seems to talk about it in the first chapter and is heavily cited
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter-Rousseeuw/publication/284537526_Robust_Regression_and_Outlier_Detection/links/60fbc1521e95fe241a84161a/Robust-Regression-and-Outlier-Detection.pdf

Comment: thank you very much @ShawnHemelstrand